# Bash queue - atomic wait & lock

Tags: multithreading, bash, queue, atomic, blockingqueue

I want to use a queue in Bash, which one process (eg. one Bash script) will be writing to and several other processes will be reading from.

I want to do this:

**writer:**

```
# block if another process is reading or writing,
# then lock the queue using an exclusive lock
lock -ex queue  
echo "$message" >> queue
unlock queue
```

**reader:**

```
# wait until there is an item in the queue
# and then lock the queue using a shared lock
wait_while_empty_and_lock -sh queue
read -r message < <(tail -n+1 queue)
(do stuff...)
unlock queue
```

Preferably, I would like to use Bash + standard / commonly available Linux/UNIX utilities (not Redis et al.). I have considered several approaches involving `flock`, several FIFOs, etc., but I couldn't come up with satisfactory results. Is there a simple way to do this in Bash/Linux/UNIX, or do I have to resort to third-party tools such as Redis?

Comment: A shared read lock will allow all the readers simultaneous access to the queue. Is that was you want? To give all readers a copy of every message? Or do you want each message to go to only one reader?

Comment: Also, will there be multiple writers? You first say there is only one and then in your writer comment you say there are multiple. Please clarify. If there will only ever be a single writer, and if the messages are newline terminated (as you imply with the `read` command) then there is no need for the writer to lock anything. The `read` command will wait for newlines so there will never be synchronization problems between the readers and the writer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I changed the design and frankly I don't remember what exactly I was originally intending to do.